# Retrieving the value from UIAlertView textbox in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app that I recently updated to deal with the UIAlertView / SubView issue that causes the textboxes to render as clear or white (or not render at all, not sure which). In any case, this is a relatively simple question as I'm kind of new to Obj-C, but how do I get the value of the new textbox from another call in the app?

Here is my UIAlertView:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password" 
                         message:@"Enter your Password\n\n\n"  
                         delegate:self 
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                         otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
alert.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 30, 300, 260);
```

It used to be stored as a UITextField, and then added to the UIAlertView as a subview:

```
    psswdField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32.0, 65.0, 220.0, 25.0)];
    psswdField.placeholder = @"Password";
    psswdField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    psswdField.delegate = self;
    psswdField.tag = 1;
    [psswdField becomeFirstResponder];
    [alert addSubview:psswdField];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

This is all commented out now, and instead I have it rewritten as:

```
 alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
```

This is how I used to retrieve the value:

```
[psswdField resignFirstResponder];
[psswdField removeFromSuperview];

activBkgrndView.hidden = NO;
[activInd startAnimating];
[psswdField resignFirstResponder];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadData:) withObject:psswdField.text];
```

Now I'm a bit confused as to how I get the value from that textbox to send to loadData.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to add your own text field to the alert view. You're not supposed to directly add subviews to a UIAlertView. There is an `alertViewStyle` property on UIAlertView that you want to set to `UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput`, which will add a text field for you. So you would set it with a line like this:

```
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
```

Then you will retrieve the value in this text field using the delegate method `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`, which you must add to the class that you're setting as your UIAlertView delegate. Here is an example implementation of that delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Make sure the button they clicked wasn't Cancel
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
        UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, makes sense. As you can see in my question I'm already doing the first part. I guess where I need help is a sample of how to to actually retrieve the text field. Again, I'm new to iOS, and I'm more of a C# guy than an obj-c one. I can get around in it, but I'm not very versed yet.

Comment: What I really need help with is: I'm assuming the alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput part creates a textbox for input. The method didDismissWithButtonIndex calls the action to do something with that textbox once the button is pressed. After is where I get hazy, how do I get the data out of that textbox in the delegate method?

Comment: I just added an example implementation of the delegate method, which will print out the value in the text field to the console when you dismiss the dialog. So you can see how you get at the text field by looking at that.